# how to know which song is playing in avaudioplayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to know which song is playing in avaudioplayer

Answer (score 0):

just get its property .url:

```
  //NO:  your.AVAudioPlayer.url;
```

EDIT:

```
yourAVAudioPlayer.url; //
```

Comment: /Users/geniusport004/Desktop/songs third/Classes/musicimages.m:62:0 /Users/geniusport004/Desktop/songs third/Classes/musicimages.m:62: error: request for member 'AVAudioPlayer' in something not a structure or union

Comment: avaudioplayer *a; how to check whether it is playing a song or not?

Answer (score 0):

The "url" property of AVAudioPlayer returns the file path of the file currently being played.

I have a feeling what you're actually asking is how to find out which song is playing in the system though. In which case you should use nowPlayingItem in MPMusicPlayerController. This shows, for example, which song is playing in iTunes.